# Why do the styles of HTML emails keep changing in Outlook?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

The problem I am currently seeing is pretty bizarre. Here are the steps that take place that cause the issue:

1. Create HTML email with multiple styles
2. Send HTML email to an email linked to Microsoft Outlook
3. Open the email in Outlook, look at it notice all of the styles
4. Wait a few days, open the email again, look at it notice some of the styles have changed

Basically without editing the email, without resending it, simply storing it in Outlook Inbox the styles are constantly changing. Examples of this include changing padding, changing bullet sizes, changing font sizes, etc.

It is very bizarre, frustrating, and confusing. Has anyone seen this issue or has anyone seen it and fixed it? Any input will be very helpful!

Thank you.

Comment: Are the styles changing to plain text, or to other, random styles? When sending a message to someone, check the Format Text tab to see if HTML is selected or Plain Text/Rich Text.

Answer (score 0):

After forwarding the HTML email, or replying on top of it, we were seeing issues with the output of HTML. This was due to the format of the email after forwarding. Thank you for the help to TylerH.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook is notorious for converting email into it's own Microsoft Word powered renderer. It basically adds a lot of junk and strips some other stuff. There are ways to code around some of this, you just have to know the quirks and make sure you are coding in best practices to avoid them.

Normally the changes are most obvious when you forward an email, are you referring to an email that is just sitting there, or has it been forwarded back and forth in a conversation? Sometimes just switching to forward/reply without actually sending it is enough to break it in the email view.

I'm not sure if you are doing anything to cause it or if it is simply breaking when it becomes automatically archived, either way, this seems to be the likely cause.